# While deploying index.ts, firebase function call in global scope requires only string literal

Tags: firebase, algolia

This two calls are failed:

```
const client = algoliasearch(functions.config().algolia.app_id, functions.config().algolia.admin_id);
const client = algoliasearch(process.env.app_id, process.env.admin_id);
```

> Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.
>
> AlgoliaSearchError: Please provide an application ID. Usage:
>   algoliasearch(applicationID, apiKey, opts)*

But this one, which requires hard coded api keys is ok:

```
const client = algoliasearch('APP_ID', 'ALGOLIA_ADMIN_KEY');
```

How can I avoid hardcoded way of initializing algolia client?

Answer (score 0):

Deploy mechanics checks if functions.config().algolia.app_id and admin_key are filled while deploying. It is good feature!!! But messages (Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.) don't allow to understand that in deploying (aka compile) time.